# Loop of duplicate questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

This question: [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items) is marked as a duplicate of:

- [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969082/unwanted-margin-in-inline-block-list-items)
- [How to remove “Invisible space” from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183341/how-to-remove-invisible-space-from-html), which is itself a dupicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items). That's right, **these duplicates form a loop**.

How does this happen? I've since tried to mark another question as a duplicate of one of the loop members, but it rejects the proposal as doing so would cause a loop! This seems like a bug.

Comment: The loop problem was resolved recently. Those questions were closed nearly an year ago.

Comment: It's a rare bug.  If you see it in the future just flag one of the questions saying that there's a circular duplicate that should be fixed.